# Keycloak : How to preview emails when working on a custom theme?

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to preview emails in Keycloak when you are working on a new custome theme ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can launch [maildev](https://github.com/maildev/maildev/blob/master/docs/docker.md) with Docker and configure the [SMTP settings](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_email) in Keycloak.

Regards,

Comment: Yes, but you have to fire a specific action every time you change the content. I meant a page where all the possible mails are displayed.

Comment: @Defoncesko did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. Only way it is to send a test connection email.

Comment: That's too bad, thanks for confirming though.